# Ускорение requests

Tags: python, requests

Мне нужно создать список артистов с Deezer, и для этого я хочу их перебрать и записать в файл. Но перебрать нужно миллионы страниц,  и я написал такой код:

```
import requests
artist_id = 14468689
for i in range(0,10000):
    r = requests.get(f'https://api.deezer.com/artist/{artist_id + i}').json()
    try:
        print(r['name'])
    except KeyError:
        print("Error")
```

Проблема в том что это относительно долго, как можно ускорить процесс?

Comment: Если вы попытаетесь ускорить процесс — сервер вас забанит за создание высокой нагрузки

Comment: Если это API то скорее всего есть другой варинат, а не ваш "топорный".